# CONVERT COBOL TEXT STRING TO NUMBER

Tags: parsing

I have a project that I'm working on where I need to take a substring that is given to me and convert it to a number.
One of the common values I have is 000300000.  This translates to 3000.00. I would LOVE to be able to figure out a way to have it display as "$3,000.00".  Can someone show me a way that I can do this?
The PARSING field looks like this:
SUBSTRING(Text,521, 9)

I've tried this: select STUFF(CAST(SUBSTRING(Text,521, 9) AS INT), LEN(CAST(SUBSTRING(Text,521, 9) AS INT), 'N0')-1, 0, '.') but am getting an argument error.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing this in COBOL!

```
01 CONVERSION.
  05 NUMBER-AS-STRING      PIC X(9).
  05 NUMBER-AS-NUMBER REDEFINES NUMBER-AS-STRING PIC 9(7)V99.
  05 NUMBER_-TO-PRINT      PIC $$$$$$9.99.

........
  MOVE '000300000' to NUMBER-AS-STRING.
  MOVE NUMBER-AS-NUMBER TO NUMBER-TO-PRINT.
  DISPLAY NUMBER-TO-PRINT
```